# Firefox flash wmode=opaque iframe problems

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, firefox

I have a html/flex app loaded in an iframe, and wmode is set to 'opaque'. I have 'mousemove' listener attached to the document of flex app and document of the parent. Once I mousedown in the flex part of iframe and move my mouse around, i can see the logs from the iframe. However, when I move the mouse around in the parent, i dont see logs from the parent. But, if I mousedown on the html part of the iframe, i can see logs from both iframe and parent.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Same sort of bug is reported in Firefox 4/5, which breaks html part of it. Visit
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625313

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the flash window is doing a capture of the mouse events which is typical in drag/drop scenarios.  If the flash code is attempting to track a drag, then it would need to be doing this capture.  I wonder if there's a way you can configured the flash app/object to only get mouse clicks and not mouse drag events, thus letting the normal mouse events as you move with the mouse down flow to whatever object is under the mouse (event outside of the flash object).  I know nothing about the Flash library, but in Google searches, I do see that it has .startDrag() and .stopDrag().  It sounds to me like you need to make sure that startDrag() is not getting called on mouse down.

Comment: no, i am not even calling startDrag() method. Since the window mode is set to opaque, javascript also receives the mousedown event which shows an image that follows the cursor by mousemove events. I guess the reason iframe keeps receiving mousemove event is because mouse is captured by flash. I tried manually dispatching mouseout and mouseleave events, but no luck.

Comment: Something in the flash environment is capturing the mouse on mouse down.

Comment: yeah, i think so too. I tried event.preventDefault() method but no luck...ahh